# Cycle2 Slideshow youtube

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, jquery-cycle2

I have a question with regards with the youtube cycle2 plugin.

Here is how the code is setup:

```
    data-cycle2-slides            ='>a'
    data-cycle2-easing            ='".$easing."' 
    data-cycle2-fx                ='".$effect."' 
    data-cycle2-timeout           ='".$timeout."' 
    data-cycle2-pause-on-hover    ='".$pause."' 
    data-cycle2-speed             ='".$speed."'
    data-cycle2-youtube            ='true'
    data-cycle2-youtube-autostart  ='true'
    data-cycle2-youtube-autostop   ='true'
```

Then this is how I'm calling the videos:

```
    <div class="slideshow cycle2-slideshow">
      <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/boi9_JIEe-Y?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0" >1</a>
      <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/srKLoOBqt0w?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" >2</a>
      <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/NLdXk21ZaYw?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0" >3</a>
      <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/KPOvBPRYkts?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0" >4</a>    
     </div>
```

I based it this on the documentation from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/video.php. The problem that I'm having is that the videos is not showing. Is there a reason why?

THank you.

Comment: Is that PHP rendering correctly? Are the data attributes being rendered correctly into HTML? Can you post what the actual HTML is?

Comment: Also, the data attributes whould be declared as part of your `.slideshow` element, so I'm not sure where those data attributes are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe declaring your data attributes in your element might help. This is the way they're supposed to be declared.

```
<div 
     class="slideshow cycle-slideshow"
     data-cycle-slides            ='>a'
     data-cycle-easing            ='".$easing."' 
     data-cycle-fx                ='".$effect."' 
     data-cycle-timeout           ='".$timeout."' 
     data-cycle-pause-on-hover    ='".$pause."' 
     data-cycle-speed             ='".$speed."'
     data-cycle-youtube            ='true'
     data-cycle-youtube-autostart  ='true'
     data-cycle-youtube-autostop   ='true'
 >
           <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/boi9_JIEe-Y?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0" >1</a>
           <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/srKLoOBqt0w?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" >2</a>
           <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/NLdXk21ZaYw?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0" >3</a>
           <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/KPOvBPRYkts?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0" >4</a>    
          </div>
```

I would also make double sure that the PHP is rendering correctly so that it doesn't mess up your HTML and data attributes.

EDIT: As the other answer mentioned, the data attributes and class should be `cycle` not `cycle2`

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things;

`cycle2-slideshow` should be `cycle-slideshow` (remove the "2")

eg. `<div class="slideshow cycle-slideshow">`

The data attributes should start with `data-cycle-XXXX` instead of `data-cycle2-XXXX`  (remove the "2")

eg. `data-cycle-slides = '>a'`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gr18b93z/)